# Can't get JSON requests working in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js

So there are a number of examples of Ember.js online but looking at this one for instance:

http://matthewlehner.net/get-started-with-ember-js-in-5-minutes/

It ends up with the following route object:

```
Test1.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
// admittedly, this should be in IndexRoute and not in the
// top level ApplicationRoute; we're in transition... :-)
model: function () {
    return ['red', 'yellow', 'blue'];
}
});
```

As a first step I would like to replace that model with a JSON request, so seeing some examples online I tried this:

```
return $.getJSON('/colors.json');
```

where colors.json is a file:

```
 ['red', 'yellow', 'blue']
```

I have tried some variations on this but it always gives me this error in my browser: "Error while loading route: undefined"

Can someone give me an idea of how to get this working?

See http://jsbin.com/lususavo/4/ for an example of the "before" state. How do I get that to work with getJSON?

Comment: You aren't showing us any code that would cause that kind of error. Can you post the rest of your code? Or, preferably, create a JSBin to reproduce the results?

Comment: Take http://jsbin.com/lususavo/4/edit for example and try to modify it so that it loads a JSON file and displays it instead of the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're wrapping everything in functions, Ember won't start until the page is ready. (I probably just don't understand it to be honest).

Either way here's an example with getJSON

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return $.getJSON('/colors.json');
  }
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/627/edit

Comment: I think the function wrapping comes from the use of ES6 magic that I don't understand. Taking your example, if I copy it to my machine and run grunt server on that directory, it will continue to work fine, but if I remove the mockjax call, it stops working even though I have a colors.jspn file in that directory and it loads fine in the browser if I enter that url. In this case I get the message "Error while processing route: index" from Ember.

Comment: if you watch the network tab, what's the actual result from the server?

Comment: 304 Not Modified. If I change the line to

    return $.ajax({
       url: '/colors.json',
       cache: false,
       dataType: 'json',
       type: 'GET'
    });

Then I get 200 OK but the error message remains the same.

Comment: Ah, I guess there was an error in the JSON. I used ' instead of ". That seems to work now. Sorry to waste everyone's time.